# How to make sub menus dynamic in the template?

Tags: django, django-cms

Here I am creating sub_menu from another sub_menu with custom template and displaying it on some particular template and which is working fine.I am providing the same template for each sub menus.
When the user selects one of the sub menu from `select` element and it gives the template which I added.Which is working as I wanted but *the issue is in the template now the sub menu disappears.*
How can i handle it.Any help would be appreciated.

template

```
 <select class="custom-select" onchange="location = this.value;">
                  <option selected>Choose</option>
                {% show_sub_menu 1 None 0 "option_menu.html" %}
              </select>
```

option_menu.html

```
{% load menu_tags  %}

{% for child in children %}

   <option value="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}">
 {{ child.get_menu_title }}</option>


{% endfor %}
```

The same template where I have sub menu with this url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/about-us/executive-boards`

[image]

The template which I assigned for the sub menu(which is same as the above template) `http://127.0.0.1:8000/about-us/executive-boards/executive-boards-2017-2019/` Now here the sub menu disapperas

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might not passing the context or show_sub_menu in url
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/about-us/executive-boards/executive-boards-2017-2019/

Comment: how can I pass then ? This is what I am asking about ?

Comment: Same way as the main view. I can't tell properly without seeing views of both urls